# Is it possible to set current dirrectory?

Tags: c, windows, working-directory

is it possible to set current directory in C(not C++)? WINDOWS XP

This is example:

path to current dir: `\current_directory\`
path to where I want to get: `\current_directory\dir_I_want_to_work_with\`

Is it possible that I can jump up on higher level directory from current directory and after that for example use function rename("file.txt","file2.txt"); ?

I tried `system("cd \destination_dir");` But it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, `system("cd \destination_dir");` works, but it applies only to the shell that has been spawned by `system()`

Comment: Please edit your question and include information of what OS you are using. The `cd` exists in multiple operative systems.

Comment: Also, make sure you escape `\ ` as `\\ ` from the path. :)

Comment: Define the environment where you're working.  Is this on the command line, in a batch file, in a C program, what?

Answer (score 4):

Try *SetCurrentDirectory* function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It is only for C++, I have to do it in C only.

Comment: It will work in C; but you need to call the Kernel32.dll function directly.

Comment: Is it? But I have no idea how to call it? ...Can me give an advice?

Comment: Hey buddy, read the link provided by the answer carefully and you'll find another link on it pointing to an **example**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it works for windows the POSIX compliant way is:

```
 int chdir(char *path)
```

This seems to be the one you are looking for

(b.t.w. this also seems to comply to the ANSI C standard. See: http://www.oocities.org/siliconvalley/peaks/8778/TAU_advprog-ANSIlib.html)

Comment: This is really comforming with [POSIX](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir), it's not an "ANSI C" function.

Comment: @unwind, Thanks for the update, I will update my answer accordingly. I had my info via http://www.oocities.org/siliconvalley/peaks/8778/TAU_advprog-ANSIlib.html

Comment: @thom: Well, I explain to you why I try to do it. I have got two char* arrays, first is list of names of files, and the second is list of new names for these files.. and I call function rename(old_names_files[counter],new_names_files[counter]); I means I need rename("destination_dir\old_name","destination_dir\new_name"); so I can do another array char* temp_name[n]; and fill it with "new_path\\" and after that I use strcat(temp_name[coutner],old_name_files[coutner]); and call rename and it should works.. but it is messy solution.... and even when I try it, it doesnt work properly.

Comment: I understand. by the way, wouldn't this be easier with a batch file ?

Comment: @thom: I have no idea how it works. I'm not such a good in programing.

Comment: in that case, don't do it and look here instead : http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/